# ArrayList: I would like to find a word in my arrayList

Tags: java, list

I have an arrayList with several elements:

```
ArrayList<String> listName = new ArrayList<String>();
    
listName.add("julie");
listName.add("sandrine");
listName.add("toto");
```

The user enters a name for example `popo`, the element doesn't exists.
However, I have several prints, I don't understand?

```
The word isn't find 
The word isn't find 
The word isn't find
```

I tried to make an algorithm:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    ArrayList<String> listName = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    listName.add("julie");
    listName.add("sandrine");
    listName.add("toto");

    System.out.println("please enter your name : ");
    String wordSearch = input.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < listName.size(); i++) {
      if (listName.get(i).equals(wordSearch)){ 
        System.out.println("The word is find : "); 
      } else {
        System.out.println("The word isn't find ");
      }
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to print it once, you need to do the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<String> listName = new ArrayList<String>();

    listName.add("julie");
    listName.add("sandrine");
    listName.add("toto");

    System.out.println("please enter your name : ");
    String wordSearch = input.nextLine();

    boolean isUserFound = false;
    for (String s : listName) {
        if (s.equals(wordSearch)) {
            isUserFound =true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(isUserFound)
        System.out.println("The word is find : ");
    else
        System.out.println("The word isn't find : ");
}
```

First find out if the user exist, set a flag accordingly and print the result also accordingly.

Or you can simply replace the loop by:

```
if(listName.contains(wordSearch))
    System.out.println("The word is find : ");
else
    System.out.println("The word isn't find : ");
```

or

```
if(listName.indexOf(wordSearch) != -1 )
    System.out.println("The word is find : ");
else
    System.out.println("The word isn't find : ");
```

Both of those methods (*i.e.,* `contains` and `indexOf`) are part of the list collection so you don't need to reimplement that logic, just used what is already there.

Full example:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<String> listName = new ArrayList<>();
        listName.add("julie");
        listName.add("sandrine");
        listName.add("toto");

        System.out.println("please enter your name : ");
        String wordSearch = input.nextLine();

        if(listName.contains(wordSearch))
            System.out.println("The word is find : ");
        else
            System.out.println("The word isn't find : ");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using an `ArrayList<String>` for your words.  Since there would, imo, be no need to house duplicates, a HashSet would be better since it's lookup is much more efficient.  A `Set` zeroes in on the location using the hashCode of the object while `List` must do a linear search.

```
Set<String> wordSet = new HashSet<String>();
    
listName.add("julie");
listName.add("sandrine");
listName.add("toto");

if (wordSet.contains(word)) {
   System.out.println(word + " was found");
} else {
   System.out.println(word + " was not found");
}
```

The downside to using a `Set` is that there is no way to do any index retrieval (which does not seem to be a requirement in your case).  Also, sets are unordered which means if you iterate thru them, they may appear in a different order in which they were added.  This latter situation can be avoided by using a `LinkedHashSet` where the order is maintained.  I suggest learning about Sets as they have many uses.

Comment: Yep using a set is definitely good advice